# Saving XML String from Kafka topic as XMLType in Oracle 19c using JDBC Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, xmltype, ora-01461

I have a Kafka topic with Avro schema

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "CaseInfo",
  "namespace": "case.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "caseid",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "caseData",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
 ]
}

Database Table case_info
caseId, varchar2
casedata, XMLType
```

I have configured a JDBC Sink Connector to insert the message from topic to database and it is having below error

ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

It seems this error comes when the data is more than 4000 chars and in my case it is almost every time more than 4000 chars.

I am able to insert XML string having more than 4000 chars directly using a insert query but it fails through JDBC Sink Connector.

Has anyone faced this before and knows how to fix it?

I tried to put XML String with less than 4000 chars and it works.